# Game Center LEaderboard Questions

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am in the process of adding Game Center to one of my apps.  What I would like to do is set up a leader board per "continent" (North America, South America, Asia, Europe, etc.).

Question 1:  If I do this, does game center have the ability to show all results for all leader boards on one leader board?  Meaning, I can allow users to see if they are top in their continent, but then also allow them to check their ranking overall.  Possible?

Question 2:  Since my app is Universal, is there a way to force the standard GC Leader board on the iPad to full screen?  I have played around with the GKLeaderBoardViewController view.bounds and although this does allow me change the size, it still maintains the original border of the default size.  Meaning, there is a square box around the middle of the view, but the data is actually expanded like it should be. (I wish I knew how to include pics here)  Have also used the modelPresentationStyle but same results with the box around a smaller portion of the screen.

Finally, concerning both questions above, is it just better to create your own custom view?  I was hoping to avoid this especially since the newer look from iOS 5 Leader boards are actually very nice.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

Geo...

Comment: Okay so it appears if you make more than 1 "single" leader board, Game Center gives you an option to create a combined leader board.  Too cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes the do allow for one main combined leader board.  Just a matter of creating a combined one and adding the others as you see fit.

As for making Game Center full screen on the iPad, no response and luck with searches.

Geo...